# Get incoming call Caller ID using a dialplan in Asterisk

Tags: database, raspberry-pi, asterisk

I'm currently doing a project with Raspberry Pi and Asterisk where I need to capture incoming caller ID and search that number on the database and later switch that call to a SIP softphone over the wifi.

I wonder if I can do all of them using a dial plan.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

For that you have use function CALLERID and function ODBC

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+callerid

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+func_odbc